# How to store variable data between frames in Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript, frames

I am new to ActionScript 3.0, I am facing a problem in storing the data from one frame to another whenever the button is clicked to switch between the frames. The original frame content is set to default.

Do we have any type(s) like session?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to store all of your data and functionality in Document Class. By moving the code off of the timeline, you gain flexibility and organization.

Here is a good introductory article to get you familiar with the concept.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/external_files_as3.html
It describes how to associate your main timeline and library symbols with external classes. This is a fundamental building block of actionscript programming and well worth the effort to learn it.